# WebStorm fails to resolve import statement

Tags: javascript, react-native, webstorm

I have a React Native project that uses package.config files in subdirectories to provide a name.  eg `{ 'name': '@subdirectory' }`.

Then, when importing in other files, we see `import foo from '@subdirectory/bar'`.

How do I configure WebStorm 2017.2.2 to accept these alias, rather than giving me 'Module not installed...'?

Comment: Marking a parent folder of `@subdirectory` as resource root (note: not the subdirectory itself, but its parent dir!) should help.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to right click your subdirectory in the project view, then
`-> Mark directory as -> Resource Root`.

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm provides no support for this React native hack (not officially documented anywhere, as far as I can tell). If you miss this feature, please follow [WEB-23221](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23221) for updates.

Marking a parent folder of `@subdirectory` as **Resource root** (note: not the subdirectory itself, but its parent dir!) should help to work out the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me - event after a **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart**.  The imports still show the "Module not installed..." hinting.

Comment: this should work - unless the `@subdirectory` doesn't match actual folder name

Comment: It does not - it is actually prefaced with @ - so, for example, we have a **/src/realm/package.json** that looks like this: `{  "name": "@realm" }`.

Comment: I see. Then marking as resource root won't help indeed

Answer (score 0):

It's just a workaround, but you can create a file with `any_name.js` along the project root directory with the following content:

```
System.config({ "paths": { 
       "@subdirectory/*": "./path/to/subdirectory/*"
      }
});
```